# Make the width of div double of its content width

Tags: html, css

For example, HTML:

```
<div style="top:0;">January</div>
<div style="top:30px;">February</div>
<div style="top:60px;">March</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

I want to add half of the original content width before and after the content, such that I have the width of each div doubled.

The effect looks like this, workaround by manually inserting inline blocks one by one:
https://jsfiddle.net/vj25udLy/13/

If I can set the width directly as 200% of its content width or some ratio else, the job seems much simpler and more flexible.

JS/jQuery solution is welcome if there is no pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 5):

A trick is to use data-attribute for the content then you add it within both pseudo-element (now you have 2x the content) then you hide one and you make the other centred:

```css
.element {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.element:before,
.element:after {
  content:attr(data-text);
}
.element:before {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.element:after {
  display:inline-block;
  transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element" data-text="January"></div>
<div class="element" data-text="February"></div>
<div class="element" data-text="March"></div>
<div class="element" data-text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"></div>
<div class="element" data-text="bb"></div>
```

Another idea if you simply want to achieve the border is to use a pseudo element and make its width 200% (or `left:-50%` and `right:-50%`):

```css
body {
  text-align:center;
}
.element {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.element:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-50%;
  right:-50%;
  bottom:0;
  height:1px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">January</div>
<br>
<div class="element">February</div>
<br>
<div class="element">March</div>
<br>
<div class="element">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<br>
<div class="element">bb</div>
```

Comment: @QuentinAlbert this is nothing, I made more horrible things :p